# Haskell--Manipulating data within a tuple

Tags: haskell, tuples

I'm attempting to simulate a checkers game using haskell.  I am given a 4-tuple named, checkersState, that I would like to manipulate with a few different functions.  So far, I have a function, oneMove, that receives input from checkerState and should return a tuple of the modified data:

The Input Tuple:

```
    (
    3600,
    "",
    [
    "----------",
    "------r---",
    "----------",
    "----------",
    "---r-r----",
    "------r---",
    "---w---w-w",
    "----------",
    "----------",
    "------w---"
    ],
    (
    49
    ,
    43  
    )
    )
```

So far I have something similar to below defining my function but am unsure how to access the individual members within the tuple checkerState.  This method will take a time, array of captured pieces, board, and move to make, and return a time, array of captured pieces, and board. Currently, I would like to modify the time (INT) in the tuple depending on the state of the board:

```
    onemove :: (Int,[Char],[[Char]],(Int,Int)) -> (Int,[Char],[[Char]])
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you considered writing a `data` type, maybe a [`Record`](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses#record-syntax) type so you could more easily access the different fields?

Comment: Haskell's support of tuples with more than two elements is somewhat limited (unless you use extra libraries like lenses), perhaps partly to discourage using them when, as others have said, making a data type usually shows clearer the intended use with your types.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use pattern-matching to pull out the elements, do whatever changes need to be made, and pack them back into a tuple. For example, if you wanted to increment the first value, you could:

```
onemove (a,b,c,d) = (a + 1,b,c,d)
```

If you find yourself doing this a lot, you might reconsider using a tuple and instead use a data type:

```
data CheckersState = CheckersState { time  :: Int       -- field names are just
                                   , steps :: [Char]    -- guesses; change them
                                   , board :: [[Char]]  -- to something that
                                   , pos   :: (Int, Int)  -- makes sense
                                   } deriving (Eq, Read, Show)
```

Then you can update it with a much more convenient syntax:

```
onemove state = state { time = time state + 1 }
```

If you want to stick with tuples and you happen to be using [lenses](https://lens.github.io/), there’s another easy way to update your tuple:

```
onemove = over _1 (+1)
```

Or if you’re using lenses *and* your own data type (with an appropriately-defined accessor like the one provided), you can do something similar:

```
_time :: Lens' CheckersState Int
_time f state = (\newTime -> state { time = newTime }) <$> f (time state)

onemove = over _time (+1)
```

So there’s plenty of fancy ways to do it. But the *most general* way is to use pattern-matching.

Comment: Unfortunately, the data structure and design choices are given by the professor.  Might i convert from the tuple to the data type and then back to a tuple once the operation has complete?  This may be overkill for the operation at hand.  I am updating the question to add more detail but your variables are in fact mostly correct.  The time data state will update depending on some condition between the board and pos moving.

Comment: @Dev: You could convert before and after the operation, I suppose, but depending on how involved the operation is, the overhead of the conversion might make it less clear than dealing with the tuples directly.

Answer (score 1):

As icktoofay is saying, using tuples is a code smell, and records with named components is way better.

Also, using Char (and String) is a code smell. To repair it, define a data type that precisely describes what you expect in a cell of the board, like `data Colour = None | Red | Black`, but see next item.

And, using Lists is also a code smell. You actually want something like `type Board = Data.Map.Map Pos Colour` or `Data.Map.Map Pos (Maybe Colour')` with `data Colour' = Red | Black`.

Oh, and Int is also a code smell. You could define `newtype Row = Row Int ; newtype Col = Col Int ; type Pos = (Row,Col)`. Possibly `deriving Num` for the newtypes, but it's not clear, e.g., you don't want to multiply row numbers. Perhaps `deriving (Eq,Ord,Enum)` is enough, with `Enum` you get `pred` and `succ`.

(Ah - this `Pos` is using a tuple, thus it`s smelly? Well, no, 2-tuples is allowed, sometimes.)

Answer (score 0):

You use [pattern matching](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Pattern_matching) to decompose the tuple into variables.

```
onemove (i, c, board, (x, y)) = <do something> (i, c, board)
```

However, you should define a separate data structure for the board to make your intention clear. I don't know what the meaning of the first two values. See: http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses